# Scrapy is ignoring part of the text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape text from websites using Scrapy and build a dataset of text and some of its features. For each element containing text I'm saving the text itself, element type and some other things. It works fine for the most part but it's not scraping part of the text which follows nested element(s).

Input example:

```
<p>
  First part of text
  <b>
    Nested text
  </b>
  Second part of text
</p>
```

Output (just an example, in reality the output is saved to csv):

```
text: First part of text, element: p
text: Nested text, element: b
```

Expected output (just an example, in reality the output is saved to csv):

```
text: First part of text, element: p
text: Nested text, element: b
text: Second part of text, element: p
```

Part of my code responsible for scraping text:

```
for element in response.xpath('//*[normalize-space(text())]'):
    ...
    text_normalized = element.xpath('normalize-space(./text())').get()
    ...
```

How do I get second part of the text? Expect that an element can contain multiple nested elements and text itself can be split in more than just 2 parts.

Comment: Not directly related to your question since you decided using xpath, but consider using beautifulsoup. It's also standard to use it alongside with scrapy, scrapy's docs itself recommends using beautifulsoup at some point. I myself worked with web scraping and it provides a set of functions for better dealing with that exact kind of situation. It's more powerful than using xpath itself

Comment: For example there are functions that allow you to recursively find <b>s instead of reaching out just the direct b's of the element you're searching on. You can also perform searchs on elements you've previously found. You can also navigate through children, parent, "brother" elements and performs searchs. It's quite useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use // with `text node` it will return all text as list and after you can use  `.join` method or list slicing.

```
text_normalized = element.xpath('normalize-space(.//p//text())').getall()
```

## Implementation on scrapy shell

```
In [1]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [2]: %paste
doc='''
<p>
  First part of text
  <b>
    Nested text
  </b>
  Second part of text
</p>
'''

## -- End pasted text --

In [3]: sel = Selector(text=doc)

In [4]: sel.xpath('//p//text()').getall()
Out[4]: 
['\n  First part of text\n  ',
 '\n    Nested text\n  ',
 '\n  Second part of text\n']

In [5]: sel.xpath('//p//text()').get()
Out[5]: '\n  First part of text\n  '

In [6]: 

In [6]: p_text=sel.xpath('//p//text()').getall()[0]

In [7]: p_text
Out[7]: '\n  First part of text\n  '

In [8]: p_text=sel.xpath('//p//text()').getall()[0].strip()

In [9]: p_text
Out[9]: 'First part of text'

In [10]: b_text=p_text=sel.xpath('//p//text()').getall()[1].strip()

In [11]: b_text
Out[11]: 'Nested text'

In [12]: p-text1=b_text=p_text=sel.xpath('//p//text()').getall()[2].strip()
  File "<ipython-input-12-6baa2c054111>", line 1
    p-text1=b_text=p_text=sel.xpath('//p//text()').getall()[2].strip()
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator


In [13]:  p_text1=b_text=p_text=sel.xpath('//p//text()').getall()[2].strip()

In [14]: p_text1
Out[14]: 'Second part of text'
```